# Static linking .dll's and cmake/qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, armadillo

I'm using the armadillo package for linear algebra with C++ which needs a couple of lapack and blas .dll's to function properly.  I'm not quite sure I understand what static linking is.  Is it possible to somehow place these .dll's "inside" the .exe so I don't need to copy them to the build directory?  If so, how do I set that up in cmake/qt creator?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot link DLLs statically. You must build the libraries as static libraries and link those. How to do that depends on the libraries. If they use autotools you need to pass

```
--enable-static --disable-shared
```

to `configure`. For anything else you'll need to consult documentation.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question/comment, but I already have the .dll's.  Are you saying I need to download the source code for lapack/blas and compile them by hand?

Comment: @Patrick I'm afraid so. Unless you find the right compiler/binary download somewhere. Why do you think you need static libraries? There's nothing wrong with moving the DLLs alongside the executables. It is actually much preferre over static linking.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help.  I'm not dead-set on static libraries or anything, it just seems a little easier than having to worry about whether or not the .dll's are in the correct folder.  Out of curiosity, why is that preferred over static linking?

Comment: I would not say that dynamic linking is de-facto preferred over static linking.  There are many scenarios where one is better than the other and vice versa.  @Patrick, If you want to statically link, you will need the static .lib files for the respective projects, and they must have the same runtime linkage or you will run into issues.

Comment: @syplex: .lib or .a files. Qt comes with MinGW GCC.

Comment: @rubenvb, the OP is talking about DLLs and EXEs, so .lib is appropriate.  I see your point is about mingw gcc, sorry I missed that.  Although odds are he is not using mingw.

Comment: if you already have compiled dll's then one thing you can do is keep the `*.exe` and `*.dll` in the same folder and everything will execute without any problem

Comment: @syplex I have the .lib files as well.  How do I do the static linking with those?  I've tried messing with cmake to make it automatically copy the .dll's over into the source directory and it's driving me crazy.

Also, I am using mingw.

Comment: .lib's are used by Visual Studio, .a files are used for mingw.  I believe there are ways to do it, but I have not done it myself.  Try searching.  http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/using-VC-lib-with-mingw-td19148.html might help.

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help, everybody.  :)